# Error: "PageMethods is not defined"

Tags: jquery, vb.net, pagemethods

Hi I am having troubles with PageMethods.

I was looking all information in stackoverflow and I couldn't get the answer for my problem.

I am working in vb.net.

In code behind I have:

```
<WebMethod()> _
Public Shared Function UpdateTime() As String
    Return Now.ToString()
End Function
```

In java call, the code is:

```
function onSuccess(data) {
    alert();
}

var json = new UsuarioSimple(username, password);

PageMethods.UpdateTime(onSuccess)
```

The webconfig is

```
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DB_PortalRPO" connectionString="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>

  <system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" validate="false"/>
    </httpHandlers>

    <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.0" />



    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Catalogs/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>


    <membership>

      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="DB_PortalRPO"
             enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false"
             maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10"
             applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </membership>

     <profile>
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/"/>
      </providers>
    </profile>

  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
     <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

My Site.Master I have the ScriptManager as:

```
<form runat="server"> 
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true" />
.
.
.
</form>
```

The login Page is:

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="Login.aspx.vb" Inherits="WebApplication3.Login1" %>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Login</title>

    <link rel="Stylesheet"  href="../../Contents/Styles/Login.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="Stylesheet"  href="../../Contents/Styles/Site.css" type="text/css" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/catalogs/account.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div class="outer">
            <div class="middle">
                <div class="login">
                    <div class="row">
                        <label>Usuario:</label>
                        <span><input type="text" id="username" /></span>
                    </div>        
                    <div class="row">
                        <label>Password:</label>
                        <span><input type="password" id="password" /></span>
                    </div>

                    <center>
                        <input type="button" id="login" value="Login" />
                    </center>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#login").click(function (ev) {
            var username = $("#username").val();
            var password = $("#password").val();

            login($.trim(username), password); // isnide login I call pagemethod which is inside a javascript web page
        });
    });
</script>
</html>
```

Always I am getting this message: 
**Uncaught ReferenceError: PageMethods is not defined**

I am working with Framework 4 and jQuery 1.11.2.
I don't know what is wrong, could somebody help me please?

Comment: and where is that `PageMethods` defined?

Comment: in a javascript file called account.js, inside a function

Comment: is that javascript file included to your page before the file that contains offending line?

Comment: yes I will set the main aspx

Comment: I added new information in the question

Comment: I found error, I was thinking I used Site.Master!!!!!! and I was working with an independent page!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the error, maybe I shoud rest for today. I misstook when I said I was working in a Site.Master when really I was working in Login.aspx which doesn't have Site.Master

grrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr

Comment: then I put in Login.aspx ScriptManager with EnablePageMethods to true,  now it is working.